# deprecated method not mentioned in javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

I have 2 classes. The first one contains a deprecated method. The second class instantiates the first one and uses its deprecated method.

The compiler does show a warning but:

Question:  why the deprecated method is not listed in the generated Java documentation after running `javadoc Test.java` ?

Here is the code:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
class Tester{
   private int a = 1;
   /**
   * @deprecated
   * This is deprecated because I do not like it
   */
   @Deprecated
   public void afficher(){
       System.out.println("a is: " + a);
   }
}
public class Test{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       Tester T = new Tester();
       T.afficher();
   }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the generated Java documentation file where the deprecated method is not listed at all:

[image]

Comment: Your class isn't public - `Tester` won't be documented *at all* at the moment. That has nothing to do with deprecation.

Comment: @JonSkeet I generated the documentation of the program above using the command I mentioned, but I just do not see the deprecated method listed

Comment: Move `Test` into his own file, and set it as a public class. then do the javadoc again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javadoc only documents public classes. Your class in which there is a deprecated method isn't public, so won't be documented.

```
javadoc Test.java
```

generates documentation for class Test. Your deprecated method is in class Tester.

Comment: thank you but previously I was asked not to use the deprecated element within the class itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968273/field-declared-deprecated-but-no-compiler-warning

Comment: Nope, you were told, that you won't be warned.

Comment: I read your answer again carefully and used the comment of @AxelH above, so it works now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

As was pointed out in the comments: the class `Tester` will not be documented, as it is not regarded as relevant for `javadoc`.
By default only `public` or `protected` are collected for documentation ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html ).

Either change its visibility (e.g. make it `protected` or `public`) or generate the javadoc with the flag `-package` or `-private`. But beware, that you may generate lots of documentation then, which you probably will not need at all.

```
javadoc -package Test.java
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-public: Shows only public classes and members.
-protected: Shows only protected and public classes and members. This is the default.
-package: Shows only package, protected, and public classes and members.
-private: Shows all classes and members.
```

So call it with javadoc -package -d *.java